# Google Cloud Storage: serve both HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google, google-cloud-storage

I'm struggling to have both HTTPS and HTTP working with a Google Storage bucket as a backend. Let's say, I want www.example.com to be served HTTP and HTTPS. The files are in a Storage Bucket.

In order to serve HTTP it is required to add DNS CNAME record to the special Google server c.googleapis... and the bucket must have the name the same as the domain name. I did that and it works.

I created a Load Balancer to enable HTTPS. I created Let's Encrypt TSL certificates and got IP of the Load Balancer. I added it to the DNS @ record.

The problem is that I want (as probably anyone else too) www to be CNAME to @.
But this way I cannot have both HTTP and HTTPS on www.example.com. Is it possible at all with bucket and Load Balancer?

Best Regards
Kamil

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an HTTP(S) load balancer, you don't need a CNAME. Instead of using a CNAME, you can configure your HTTP(S) load balancer to support both SSL (port 443) and non-SSL (port 80) on a single IP.